# Angular2 npm start fails

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-start

I have a function to change the classname for a DOM element in my angular component class. I get an error that

> Property style does not exists on type Element

when trying to build. The build exists with status code 2 and then npm serve does not run.

However if I remove this function, npm start works fine and I get the page. Then once the re-introduce the code, everything works fine.

Here is the component code

```
 import { Component , AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Handsontable: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'fsiapp',
  templateUrl: "/templates/dashboard.html"
})

export class FsiMainComponent {

    openTab(tabName:any) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("maps");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"; 
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-button");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = "tab-button";
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName+"b").className = "tab-button selected"; 
    }


    toggleEdit(){
        if(document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML == "Edit") {
            document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = "Save";
            document.getElementById("advName").className = "textbox";
            document.getElementById("advRate").className = "textbox";
            document.getElementById("advAddress").className = "textbox";
            document.getElementById("advEmail").className = "textbox";
            document.getElementById("advPhone").className = "textbox";
            document.getElementById("advFax").className = "textbox";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = "Edit";
            document.getElementById("advName").className = "textboxread";
            document.getElementById("advRate").className = "textboxread";
            document.getElementById("advAddress").className = "textboxread";
            document.getElementById("advEmail").className = "textboxread";
            document.getElementById("advPhone").className = "textboxread";
            document.getElementById("advFax").className = "textboxread";
        }
        this.readonly = !this.readonly
        }   

    private readonly:boolean = true;
    container: any;
    hot: any;
    container1: any;
    hot1: any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.container = document.getElementById('example');
        this.container1 = document.getElementById('example1');
        this.hot = new Handsontable(this.container, {
            data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(7, 3),
            cells: function (row:any, col:any, prop:any) {

                var cellProperties:any;

                cellProperties.readOnly = true;

                if (this.instance.getData()[row][col] === 'cell value here') {
                    // code based on cell value 
                }

                if (row % 2 === 0) {
                    //changing style based on row number
                    cellProperties.renderer = function (instance:any, td:any, row:any, col:any, prop:any, value:any, cellProperties:any) {
                        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                        //td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                        //td.style.color = 'green';
                        td.style.background = '#F1F1FF';
                    }
                }


                return cellProperties;
            },
            rowHeaders: false,
            colHeaders: ["FSI Date","FSI Name","FSI Count"],
            // performance tip: set constant size
            width: 320,
            height: 120,
            colWidths: 100,
            rowHeights: 5,
            columnSorting: true,
            sortIndicator: true,
            // performance tip: turn off calculations
            autoRowSize: false,
            autoColSize: false
        });

        this.hot1 = new Handsontable(this.container1, {
            data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(20, 6),
            cells: function (row:any, col:any, prop:any) {

                var cellProperties:any;

                cellProperties.readOnly = true;

                if (this.instance.getData()[row][col] === 'cell value here') {
                    // code based on cell value 
                }

                if (row % 2 === 0) {
                    //changing style based on row number
                    cellProperties.renderer = function (instance:any, td:any, row:any, col:any, prop:any, value:any, cellProperties:any) {
                        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                        //td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                        //td.style.color = 'green';
                        td.style.background = '#F1F1FF';
                    }
                }


                return cellProperties;
            },
            rowHeaders: false,
            colHeaders: ["FSI Date","Advertiser","FSI Name", "Barcode","Coverage","Track Status"],
            // performance tip: set constant size
            width: 700,
            height: 300,
            colWidths: 115,
            rowHeights: 5,
            columnSorting: true,
            sortIndicator: true,
            // performance tip: turn off calculations
            autoRowSize: false,
            autoColSize: false
        });


    }





}
```

Here is the error I get during build

```
> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build D:\dropbox\Dropbox\angular\fsiapp
> tsc -p src/

src/app/fsi-main.component.ts(15,9): error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exi
st on type 'Element'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart pa
ckage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\108630\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-14T18_15_22
_557Z-debug.log
```

Here is the npm build log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prebuild: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: PATH: D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\dropbox\Dropbox\angular\fsiapp\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\dropbox\Dropbox\angular\fsiapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\PTools020000000
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: CWD: D:\dropbox\Dropbox\angular\fsiapp
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc -p src/' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\dropbox\Dropbox\angular\fsiapp
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
19 error node v7.9.0
20 error npm  v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 2
23 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
23 error Exit status 2
24 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     tsc -p src/
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Comment: Initially it looks like whatever is being returned from your DOM selector "maps", is a collection of elements of which at least one does not have the property "style". 

The first thing I would do is eyeball what's in that element collection, set a breakpoint in your debugger or trace it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3263

`Element`s do not have a `style` property.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

You can cast the variables into `HTMLElement`s instead:

```
var x = <HTMLElement> document.getElementsByClassName("maps");
```

or just use `any` if you don't need the type-checking and auto-complete.

```
var x: any = document.getElementsByClassName("maps");
```

Comment: Is this true of a standard html dom selector, as in they hijacked it, like the way they hijacked intervals and whatnot? If so, ugh...

Comment: @TimConsolazio I haven't dug that deep sir :-) they say "_We do generate these from IE's definitions_" tho

Comment: Ah, at last, the true face of TypeScript is revealed. IE Standards enforcement, Microsoft Rising! "Just a superset" my arse. Some IE 8 engineer stuck in the dark for five years is gleefully cackling.

Comment: I tried casting using var HTMLCollectionOf<Element> but i still receive the same error. If I use "any", i get the following new error:  Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'x' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>'.

Comment: @AshishDhandharia but you are not doing what I wrote. `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>` is still an `Element`. You should cast it to `HTMLElement`. If you are going to use `any` cast it to `any` everywhere. You are casting it to something in the beginning and casting it to something else at the end

Comment: @echonax yes I corrected as suggested and it is working fine now.